# Elimination of bromine with sodium iodide and electrocyclization

Tags: organic-chemistry, elimination, rearrangements

I've been trying to solve the following reaction scheme for a while now and I am having trouble especially with the products **E** and **F**.

> [image]

For product **D** I got the following, but I'm unsure about compound **E**, which should be a reactive intermediate.

> [image]

While trying to figure out the structure of compound **E**, I drew the following structure, but I'm not sure how the rearrangements will happen to get rid of the charges and get product **E**. I do expect that **E** won't be aromatic but that **F** will be.

> [image]

All in all, I am wondering what products **E** and **F** will be and how to figure them out.

Comment: There are no charges in E. Calculate the degree of unsaturation of E. There is no benzene ring in E.

Comment: I know the IHD is 5, but how can I determine where the double/triple bonds will be?

Comment: For E you have a degree of unsaturation of 5, one of which is a ring. So how do you introduce 4 double bonds (forget triple bonds) into the carbon framework?  Put the two bromine atoms in their most stable orientation.

Comment: F arises as a racemate from a conrotatory electrocyclization of E.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, this really helped!

Comment: I hope you got "I", which was, for some reason, the only species without data. If you want, I'll post an answer.

Comment: I think I got the compound "I", but I am a bit unsure whether my compound "H" is correct. Hence an answer would be very helpful, so I could check.

Comment: Working on it now!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pöytä: Your conclusion that **D** contains four bromine atoms symmetrically distributed is sound. The treatment of **D** with NaI serves to substitute one, if not two bromine atoms with iodine to form "**J**". Iodide acts as a reducing agent in a vinylogous fashion. (Compare this reaction with the reduction of a vicinal dibromide with iodide to form an alkene.) The stereochemistry of **E** is likely to be *E,E* which arises from a transition state for elimination that avoids steric interactions involving bromine. I am assuming that the "electrocyclization" is thermal since there is no indication that light was involved. Achiral **E** will undergo a conrotatory electrocyclization in two directions to give racemic **F** and, eventually, diiodide **G** via S<sub>N</sub>2 displacement. (The electrocyclization may be rationalized as involving the HOMO of a butadiene or octatetraene. [Look here](http://ursula.chem.yale.edu/~chem220/chem220js/STUDYAIDS/pericyclic/pericyclic.htm) for a discussion.) Reductive elimination of iodine via Zn-Cu couple affords benzocyclobutadiene **H**. (The elimination is akin to the formation of ethylene from 1,2-dibromoethane with magnesium.) The strained, reactive double bond of **H** undergoes a Diels-Alder reaction with cyclopentadiene to form adduct **I**. The stereochemistry shown arises from a so-called "endo" transition state.
I found this question somewhat amusing in that information was provided for all species save the final product. ;)

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Seems like I did it correctly after your tip about the degree of saturation.

Comment: Just a technical note: **H** should be in squire parenthesis since it is unstable. Also, it would ne nicer to include a reference for relevant reactions, *e.g.*, https://doi.org/10.1021/ja01583a071.

Comment: This would be better reference: https://doi.org/10.1021/cr60266a002.

Comment: The 50 year old review covers the early steps of the sequence of reactions and it provides an historical perspective. I don't recall seeing any examples of electrocyclizations. Good find nonetheless.

Comment: Typo alert, **H** is actually benzocyclobutadiene not benzocyclobutene.

Comment: @Ron: Oops! Done.